# $ X \geq Y $ sufficient for monotonic likelihood ratio?

Tags: probability, statistics

Suppose that $X$ and $Y$ are random variables and $$X \geq Y $$ pointwise. Let $f_X(\cdot)$ and $f_Y(\cdot)$ be the density function2 of $X$ and $Y,$ respectively. Is it true that the likelihood ratio $$f_X(\cdot) / f_Y(\cdot)$$ is a non-decreasing function? (That is, the monotonic likelihood ratio property holds.)

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

No.  Suppose $f_X(x) = f_Y(x-1)$, as would happen if $X=Y+1$ almost surely. Take for example $f_Y(x)= \frac 1{\pi(1+x^2)}$, so $R(x) = f_X(x)/f_Y(x) = (1+x^2)/(1+(x-1)^2)$.  This is not monotonic on $\mathbb R$, as can be seen by the facts that $\lim_{x\to\pm\infty}R(x) = 1$ and $R(x)$ is not a constant function.

Comment: Thank you for this answer.